# Почему коммит прерывается с ошибкой "Aborting commit due to empty commit message"?

Tags: git, git-commit

пытаюсь сделать `commit` в `git`, пишу команду

```
git commit
```

Выводит описание комита через `gedit` (я думаю это не сильно важно каким текстовым редактором пользоваться?), я сохраняю изменения и закрываю его. И выводится

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit
message.
```

Всё прекрасно работает с помощью

```
git commit -m 'commit'
```

Но хотелось бы до конца разобраться. Кто-то может подсказать, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Читайте внимательно сообщения об ошибках. Та, что у вас, говорит о том, что не задано описание для коммита. В вылезшем окошке gEdit необходимо указать описание для коммита в первой строчке файла, записать файл и выйти.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: ["git commit" fails if gedit is already opened](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1100415)

Баг найден в феврале, до сих пор не пофиксан.

Comment: Не баг оказался, а невнимательность(

Comment: Мне кажется, там просто не хватает параметра `-w` : `"git config --global core.editor gedit -w". И баг сразу исправится.

Comment: Спасибо, ответ помог выяснить что проблема была в уже открытом редакторе.

Answer (score 0):

Очень может быть, что при указании текстового редактора для git, вы не поставили флаг `-w` (wait).

Попробуйте так:

```
git config --global core.editor "'путь_до_редактора/gedit.exe' -w"
```